# Receiving TypeError when loading new popup menu

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm using PySimpleGui to create GUI for my program, I'm creating a settings tab however when I click the settings tab I'm receiving an error that states "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" I've ran my code through the debugger and it shows all the way through that "settings" is in fact initialized and has information stored in it, so I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

The configuration of my settings:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SETTINGS_PATH = str(Path.cwd())
    settings = sg.UserSettings(
        path=SETTINGS_PATH, filename="config.ini", use_config_file=True, convert_bools_and_none=True
    )
    theme = settings["GUI"]["theme"]
    font_size = int(settings["GUI"]["font_size"])
    font_family = settings["GUI"]["font_family"]
    sg.theme(theme)
    sg.set_options(font=(font_family, font_size))
    main_window()
```

The if statement I'm running in my event loop:

```
if event == "Settings":
        settings_window(settings)
```

and lastly my settings function:

```
def settings_window(settings1):
    settings_layout = [
        [sg.Text("Settings")],
        [sg.Text("Font"), sg.Combo(settings1["GUI"]["font"], default_value="Arial", key="-FONT-")],
        [sg.Text("Font Size"), sg.Combo(settings1["GUI"]["font_size"], default_value=12, key="-FSIZE-")],
        [sg.Text("Theme"), sg.Combo(settings1["GUI"]["theme"])],
        [sg.Button("Save Settings")]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("Settings Window", settings_layout, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Save Settings"):
            break
    window.close()
```

Edit: I decided to throw all the code in one thing as well so you can see where everything is laid out:

```
def settings_window(settings1):
    settings_layout = [
        [sg.Text("Settings")],
        [sg.Text("Font"), sg.Combo(settings1["GUI"]["font"], default_value="Arial", key="-FONT-")],
        [sg.Text("Font Size"), sg.Combo(settings1["GUI"]["font_size"], default_value=12, key="-FSIZE-")],
        [sg.Text("Theme"), sg.Combo(settings1["GUI"]["theme"])],
        [sg.Button("Save Settings")]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("Settings Window", settings_layout, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Save Settings"):
            break
    window.close()


def main_window():
    window_title = settings["GUI"]["title"]
    window = sg.Window(window_title, layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
            break
        if event == "Convert":
            if is_valid_path(values["-IN2-"]):
                try:
                    _download_song(values["-IN-"], values["-IN2-"])
                except pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
                    sg.popup_error("Invalid YouTube Link")
        if event == "Settings":
            settings_window(settings)

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SETTINGS_PATH = str(Path.cwd())
    settings = sg.UserSettings(
        path=SETTINGS_PATH, filename="config.ini", use_config_file=True, convert_bools_and_none=True
    )
    theme = settings["GUI"]["theme"]
    font_size = int(settings["GUI"]["font_size"])
    font_family = settings["GUI"]["font_family"]
    sg.theme(theme)
    sg.set_options(font=(font_family, font_size))
    main_window()
```

Comment: Maybe the file `config.ini` not existing, so `settings["GUI"]["font_size"]` is None.

Comment: @JasonYang The config file does exist, it's in the root directory, and when ran through the debugger I can see the settings variable have all the information I've put it in stored

Comment: Or there's no `["GUI"]["font_size"]` in your config.ini file.

Comment: So my config file has title, font_size, font_family, and theme. Prior to me creating the whole "settings_window" function, I had the settings button just pop out a window showing the config folder to make sure it works. It wasn't until after I created the rest of the function that it stopped working